# Create new objects from ArrayList<E> items

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to create several new objects from an ArrayList. Suppose my list is:

```
ArrayList<InvVoucher> list = .....;
int index = 0;
InvVoucher vch1 = list.get(index);
InvVoucher vch2 = list.get(index);
InvVoucher vch3 = list.get(index);
```

Here `vch1`, `vch2` and `vch3` are holding the same object reference. How can I make all of them independent? How can I get three different copy of `InvVoucher`?

Comment: Use the class' constructor to create new instances.

Comment: If InvVoucher has a copy constructor, you can make a new instance with `InvVoucher vch1 = new InvVoucher(list.get(index)):`

Comment: Your question is: how do you create a copy of an object? It is not important if the original object came out of an ArrayList. You could address this by either creating a new `InvVoucher` constructor which takes one argument – another `InvVoucher` instance – and copies values from it. Or you could create a `clone()` method on `InvVoucher` and use that.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement a copy constructor in `IntVoucher` as suggested in the comments.

```
public class IntVoucher {
    public IntVoucher(IntVoucher original) {
        this.field1 = new Field1(original.field1);
        ...
    }
    private Field1 field1;
    ...
}
```

That way you can do

```
IntVoucher vch1 = new IntVoucher(list.get(index));
```

Another possibility is overriding the `clone` method in `IntVoucher` and having it implement the `java.lang.Cloneable` interface.

```
public class IntVoucher implements Cloneable {
    // note: change from protected to public if needed
    protected IntVoucher clone() {
       IntVoucher clone = new IntVoucher();
       clone.field1 = new Field1(this.field1);
       ...
       return clone;
    }
    private Field1 field1;
    ...
}
```

Read more on shallow / deep copying in Java. There are lots of complete examples if this isn't enough.

Comment: That is not how you implement `clone()` in Java, see [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Cloneable.html)